# Is Jank-free page load & scrolling possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, rendering

Im looking more into performance lately, how to improve the critical rendering path, have al page interaction at 60FPS and such.

Even though a particular page I was analyzing was loading under 400ms and it's scroll down(table: 100 rows with color changes on links and rows on hover) was fluent with apparently no issues. When inspecting the timeline in Chrome I found plenty of Jank.

I applied to the body the following css (css -> "pointer-events:none;") just to see if the Jank would disappear if I would avoid activating hover effects during scroll down but the Jank remain.

I decided to go to csstriggers.com just for the sake of curiosity and recorded both the page load and scroll down of their page. And Jank I found even though apparently no issue on page load time or bad/slow interaction.

load:

[image]

scroll:

[image]
[image]

What does it mean and how can it be fixed when blocks of jank appear for example 70.2ms but only contain a very small amount of time with render or paint and rest of time is "ms other" or "idel"?

Is a 100% jank free load and scroll possible or is it enough performance quality when the feeling during interaction and load seems allright?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help much but instead of disabling pointer-events, try a loader screen. If user's connection is slow, it might take little more than 400ms and user will see page but will not be able to use it.

Comment: I applied it just as a test case but still Jank. Any way the toggle of that property would be linked to the window.onscroll event or similar.

Comment: My point was to give a loader screen so that user doesn't observe lag. Show only when entire page rendering is completed.

Comment: Ok I c. Yes in the real app I am improving performance wise I use cg-busy(angular world). But the reason for this post is more of a conceptual question. "Is jank-free scroll or load a realistic goal when apparently no issue exists"

Comment: I'm not very experienced but my best guess would be no. You can optimize your code but not how html works. Try loading to much of data say 10000 rows with 100 columns each. Now scroll will have lag even if all processing is done. Also I guess, this was the reason why ng-grid was parked and ui-grid was created.